# Facebook doesn't work with Chromium, works fine with Firefox

Tags: firefox, chromium

My Facebook doesn't work with Chromium, but it works fine with Firefox.

Comment: What kind of error do you get?

Comment: You need to provide more information. What version of Chromium? In what way does it not work? Please edit your question so people can understand the problem.

Comment: Does this mean Flash-based games on Facebook?

Comment: ok, the problem solved when I reinstall the chromium

Answer (score 3):

As you stated yourself in a comment, after you re-installed chromium everything worked.

Comment: Did he purge `chromium` and then install it? Or just `reinstall`?

Comment: @ThomasBoxley His comment didn't specify.